# issues in integrating gmail login in android app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i want to make a swiggy type app. i have integrated gmail login in my login screen and it changes to dashboard activity on success but when i click on account tab it goes back to dashboard screen instead of account activity. pls help......

[login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/827N1.png)

[dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkD6X.png)

if you want any portion of code just comment and i will update

```
//login screen part
//check if already signed in using google
account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);

        if(account!=null) {
            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DashboardActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return;
        }


//onclicklistener added
//method
private void googleSignin() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

onActivity result(//params provided){
if(googleLogin){
            // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
            if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
                // a listener.
                googleLogin = false;                      //set to false so that it can be set true again if login is actually successful
                Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
                handleSignInResult(task);
            }

        }
}
private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {

        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            sessionManager.setLogin(true);
            googleLogin = true;

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,DashboardActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("googleLogin", googleLogin);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();


        }

//Dashboard part
 Intent i = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this ,MyAccountActivity.class);
i.putExtra("googleLogin", googleLogin);
startActivity(i);


//myaccount part
 if(googleLogin){
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
            if (acct != null) {
                String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
                //System.out.println(personName);          working fine
                account_name.setText(personName);

                String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
                //System.out.println(personEmail);         fine
                account_email.setText(personEmail);

                account_mobile.setText("+91 1234567890");

//                System.out.println(googleLogin);
//                System.out.println(fbLogin);
            }

        }
```

Comment: You have to post the code here as this is logical error as I found. If you need help you have to share code block where you are having this problem.

Comment: thats the thing there is no error in logcat. app doesn't crash or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this problem.
the issue was gmail was not able to provide account details for use when i tried to display them in MY ACCOUNT activity that i integrated in my app, thats why it kept on getting crashed. the code was correct thats why it wasnt giving any error i even tried logging it. there it showed correct details but still it wasnt displaying the result in text views.
so what i did was use shared preferences. everytime the user logs in using gmail, the details are stored in them and i retrieve it in MY ACCOUNT activity and yes it displayed the results correctly.
let me know if you need any more help.